# How to align a texview to the center

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Android - How can I align the text to the center , the left texviews ¨t¨and ¨c¨should be align with the center of the imageview and the right textview ¨localTime" , why are they on top ?

Thanks Stackoverflow

[Heres a pic of my layout , can see the difference ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiT96.jpg)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:weightSum="3.0" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/localTimestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="localTime"
         />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="right|bottom"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:text="w"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_weather"
            android:layout_width="25dip"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weather"
            android:background="@drawable/w_1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:gravity="right|bottom" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperature"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_weather"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:text="@string/t"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unitTemp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/temperature"
            android:text="@string/c"
             />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

`android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

for both of textviews

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperature"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_weather"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:text="t" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unitTemp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/temperature"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="c" />
```

[image: view]

Comment: Welcome...Designing is always my fav thing in android ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/localTimestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="localTime"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:text="w"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_weather"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/w_1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperature"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/t"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unitTemp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/c"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Haresh is right. I am using almost same. Just remove string.

My xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:weightSum="3.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/localTimestamp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="localTime" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weather"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right|bottom"
                android:text="w"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_weather"
                android:layout_width="25dip"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weather"
                android:gravity="right|bottom" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/temperature"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_weather"
                android:gravity="right|bottom" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/unitTemp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/temperature"
                android:gravity="right|bottom" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```